# Symbols to hex integer conversion

Tags: c#, ascii

I got a string of symbol "↕?0♠▬hIR W}?? caq?               ☺     ??  ♦?♫x" which I want to convert it to a hex string. For example, after conversion of "☺", variable hex will become "01" and " " will become "00". The conversion table can be found here http://www.jimprice.com/ascii-dos.gif

But I do not know how to code it in c#, can anyone help?

```
string test = "☺";
Console.WriteLine("{0}", test);
byte[] b = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(test);
var hex = BitConverter.ToString(b);
Console.WriteLine("{0}", hex);
```

That is the code I have for now, but "☺" gets treated like a "?" and printed "3F". Sorry I do not know what conversion it is and thanks in advance.

Comment: maintain the array which you shared in the image with hex code instead of symbols. use same snippets to find code from the array.

Comment: sorry @SushilMate, I dont get you, is it possible to have some code for testing?

Comment: Try this :             string input = "↕?0♠▬hIR W}?? caq? ☺ ?? ♦?♫x";
            string output = string.Join(",", input.Select(x => "0x" + ((byte)x).ToString("x2")).ToArray());

Comment: There are already lots of questions on Stack Overflow involving the conversion of text to ASCII or other encoding values, and lots of questions involving converting numeric values to hexadecimal. Please see the marked duplicate for one of the older examples of this; I've added details to the accepted answer to make sure you can easily apply it to your own case. Note that, based on the table you've referenced, you are in fact one of those people saying they are using ASCII, but in fact are using something else (probably CP 1252).

Comment: string input = "↕?0♠▬hIR W}?? caq? ☺ ?? ♦?♫x";
            string output =  string.Join(",", input.ToCharArray().Select(x => (int) x));
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", output);
            string convertBackInput = string.Join(",", output.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).Select(y => (Char) y));
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", convertBackInput);

Answer (score 0):

You have a sequence of bytes that somehow ends up in a string. That's not the right way to store bytes. A byte is an 8 bit value while the characters that make up a .NET string are 16 bit values. In your sample code the character `☺` is represented by the 16 bit value `0x263A` in the string and not `0x01` or `0x0001` as you expect.

To convert between a sequence of bytes and a string you need an encoding. In your case you want to interpret the bytes as ASCII characters which makes your problem solvable in some roundabout way.

To convert each character to a byte you can simply cast the character to a byte. When the character is represented by `0x0001` it will be cast to the byte `0x01` as expected. However, when the character is `0x263A` (`☺`) it will be cast to `0x3A` which represents a `:` using ASCII encoding so this will only work for ASCII characters.

Putting it all together (`test` is your string that is storing ASCII bytes):

```
var bytes = test.Select(ch => (byte) ch);
var bytesAsHexStrings = bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"));
```

However, getting rid of the string in the first place and simply accessing the bytes that was used to create the string is the proper way to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Possible that the text is Unicode. I think Encoding.Default is ANSI code page.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode(v=vs.110).aspx

Using Encoding.Unicode (or one of the other encodings) might fix it.

Comment: I have tried to change Encoding.Default to Encoding.Unicode or any other ones (UTF7, UTF8, UTF32...), the result of hex will be 3A-26. It is not the correct solution and thanks for look into it

Comment: The text shown in the question contains only characters that appear in the ASCII range, 0-127. The table the OP shows is not ASCII, but rather looks like code page 1252 or some similar old OEM/DOS code page. But in any case, guessing at the encoding doesn't really answer the _question_ itself.